# How to customize sharepoint online mega menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Lzf.jpg)I have implemented megamenu in share point online pages. How to add a background color to mega menu?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) Remember that context is key, the more you provide, the more the community can help you (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build the SPFx solution package from here : https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss

Then create a custom css file to change the background of mega menu and upload to style library.